# How To Run Grails 2.4.1 With Servlet 2.5

Tags: grails

Grails version 2.4.1 was recently released.  One of the bugs fixed was restoring the ability to use servlet version 2.5.  See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11466

I created a new grails app.  Without changing anything, I was able to compile it and run it.  When I changed the grails.servlet.version to "2.5", I was able to compile but when I ran it I got the the following stack trace error.

Does anyone know if there are other settings I need to change to get Grails 2.4.1 to run on a servlet 2.5 container? Specifically, tomcat 6.

```
Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/async/api/ControllersAsyncApi;
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredFields(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1593)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.async.api.ControllersAsyncApi
    ... 21 more
Error |
Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error would happen if you didn't do a `grails clean` prior to running Grails after changing the version to 2.5

What happens is that when the version is 3.0 Grails adds extra dependencies to the classpath that result in new behaviour being added to the compiled classes.

If you then change the version to 2.5 and just do `run-app` the extra dependencies are gone, but the new behaviour is still compiled into the classes. Doing a `clean` resolve this.